# How to use maven archetype in intellij idea, such as spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-archetype

I'm a newbie of maven. These day, I want to create a spring mvc project, so I find [spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype](https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype), but how to use it in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 2):

1) Add the Plugin "Maven Archetype Catalogs" to Intelij

```
1.1) File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse repositories...

1.2) Search for "Maven archetype" and look for the "Maven Archetype Catalogs"

1.3) Click on Install button of that plugin. After finished click the restart intelij button
```

2) Create a New Project on Intelij based on Spring Boot Simple Archetype

```
2.1) File -> New -> Project

2.2) Check the option "Create from archetype" and click the Add Archetype button

2.3) Fill the fields with the archtetype information you want o use

    GroupId: org.springframework.boot
    ArtifactId: spring-boot-sample-simple-archetype
    Version: 1.0.2.RELEASE
    Repository: http://central.maven.org/maven2/

2.4) Click OK
```

This will tell the intelij to download the new archetype and create a new maven project
    based on this archetype you selected, in this case will generate a project using Spring Boot CommandLinner

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean how to use it? Just import an existing maven project into your IDE after you've created it using the archetype.

http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_and_importing_Maven_projects

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Just clone the archetype and `mvn install` it, then we can use the archetype.